# opengl es gldrawelements function causes memory access violation

Tags: opengl-es, vbo

I'm learning OpenGL ES now and copying and modifying some examples from blue book.
The example was simply drawing a red triangle on black background; I made it and it worked.

So I changed it into a cube drawing and it worked as well.
But as soon as I change it to use VBO and IBO, it crashes in glDrawElements function with memory access violaiton 0x00000005.

I searched many sites to find out the reason but I was able to find any that helped.

Would you find any problem in my code?

**Change Note**

- I replaced cube with triangle.
- I checked all gl/egl functions if they produce any error, but they didn't.

I'm using OpenGL ES 1.3 vertsion.

```
struct Vertex
{
GLfloat x;
GLfloat y;
GLfloat z;
};


void NewTriangle( Vertex*& vertices, GLuint& verticesCount, GLubyte*& indices, GLuint& indicesCount )
{
    verticesCount = 3;
    vertices = new Vertex[verticesCount];
    vertices[0] = Vertex( 0, 0 );
    vertices[1] = Vertex( -0.5, -0.5 );
    vertices[2] = Vertex( 0.5, -0.5 );
    indicesCount = 3;
    indices = new GLubyte[indicesCount];
    indices[0] = 0;
    indices[1] = 1;
    indices[2] = 2;
}

void NewVerticesAndIndices( Vertex*& vertices, GLuint& verticesCount, GLubyte*& indices, GLuint& indicesCount )
{
    NewTriangle( vertices, verticesCount, indices, indicesCount );
    //NewCube( vertices, verticesCount, indices, indicesCount );
}

void RenderCommon( Vertex*& vertices, GLuint& verticesCount, GLubyte*& indices, GLuint& indicesCount )
{
    const GLfloat color[] = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
    glVertexAttrib4fv( 0, color );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const void*)vertices );

    glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, indicesCount, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (const void*)indices );
}

void RenderWithMemories( Vertex*& vertices, GLuint& verticesCount, GLubyte*& indices, GLuint& indicesCount )
{
    RenderCommon( vertices, verticesCount, indices, indicesCount );
}

void RenderWithVBO( const GLuint& vbo, const GLuint& ibo, Vertex*& vertices, GLuint& verticesCount, GLubyte*& indices, GLuint& indicesCount )
{
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesCount*sizeof(*vertices), (void*)vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo );
    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesCount*sizeof(*indices), (void*)indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    GLuint vboOffset = 0;
    GLuint iboOffset = 0;
    RenderCommon( (Vertex*&)vboOffset, verticesCount, (GLubyte*&)iboOffset, indicesCount );
}

void BlueEyeApp::OnRender()
{
    glViewport( 0, 0, 640, 480 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glUseProgram(m_program);

    GLuint verticesCount;
    Vertex* vertices = NULL;
    GLuint indicesCount;
    GLubyte* indices = NULL;
    NewVerticesAndIndices( vertices, verticesCount, indices, indicesCount );

    //RenderWithMemories( vertices, verticesCount, indices, indicesCount ); // successfully output
    RenderWithVBO( m_vbo, m_ibo, vertices, verticesCount, indices, indicesCount ); // crashes

    eglSwapBuffers( GetDisplay(), GetSurface() );

    delete[] vertices;
    delete[] indices;
}
```

and I have this in my initialization :

```
bool BlueEyeApp::CreateBuffers()
{
    glGenBuffers( 1, &m_vbo );
    glGenBuffers( 1, &m_ibo );
    return true;
}
```

I wonder if it has something to do with egl version, since my major & minor version of the result of eglInitialize is 1.3. I don't know what the versions mean; I thought I have opengl es 2.0 or higher.

I also checked all the gl/egl function error checking and there were no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite old posting, but I solved this problem a long time ago.
As soon as I change my Opengl ES library file, everything worked fine.

It was very weird to me that I checked every single glCode with glError and nothing was detected.
But as soon as glDrawElement get called, the program crashed.
And the problem has gone as I change gles library file.
I want to specify to which version I moved on to but I don't remember.

Hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is your only problem, but you can't call `glBindAttribLocation` where you are currently.

`glBindAttribLocation` only takes effect the next time you link the program is linked after you call it. If you call it after linking it does nothing.

Either bind your attributes before linking your shader, or use `glGetAttribLocation` to find the attribute locations after the program is linked.

Comment: Hey, Tim. Thanks for your answer and I think it was the main reason my program crashes.

Comment: I didn't test if it stops crashing, but I guess you pointed out the main problem of my code. I had another problem that is drawing is shown on my mac windows but not on my workplace computer, and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I'll try at home with VBO and choose your answer as best. Thank you very much

Comment: Hello, Tim. I tested it and it does not work. Still crashes on "glDrawElements."
Someone said it might be the problem of grahphics driver. Can this be that case? Thanks for your sincerity.

Comment: @user1687923 - I suppose anything could technically be the fault of a bad driver, but I don't expect it would trip up on something so simple. Generally you get crashes on glDrawElements when you're sampling past the bounds of an array into protected memory. All I can recommend is liberal use of glGetError everywhere to check if there are any errors before the crash. Also anytime you update your code to try something new, I would recommend that you update your post with the latest code. Then someone can see if you've caused a different problem by your modifications.

Comment: @user1687923 - Also maybe try simplifying to see if it gets you anywhere. Try just drawing a single triangle and see if it works. You can try with glDrawArrays as another thing to try. You may find your own error as you see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Hi, Tim. Thanks for reply. I was not able to fix my program yet. I updated my source code to recent and made it readable and easy to testable for normal case. It worked without vbo, but doesn't work with vbo.

Comment: Hi, Tim. I just changed opengl es library with my friend's es library and it works now. I guess my library was somewhat buggy. Thanks for your teachings, and they were really helpful to me.^^